# UIActivityViewControllerでFacebookにシェアできない

Tags: ios, objective-c

以前まで正常に動作していましたが、
突然Facebookへのシェアができなくなりました。
ActionSheetが表示され、Facebookのアイコンをタップすると
テキストが空の状態になってしまいます。

以下のログが出ているようなのですが、
対策をご存知の方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

**plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated**

```
- (IBAction)Share{
NSString　*shareText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_contents_decscription];
NSArray *postItem = @[shareText];
UIActivityViewController *ShareActivity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                           initWithActivityItems:postItem applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:ShareActivity animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この現象は私も確認しています。
私が確認している現象は、
・テキストのみを埋め込んだ場合、UIActivityViewControllerにFacebookのアイコンが出ない。
・テキスト+イメージを埋め込んだ場合、UIActivityViewControllerにFacebookのアイコンは出るが、投稿画面はイメージのみ表示されて、テキストが表示されない。(ユーザが入力したテキストはイメージとともに投稿できる)

本家StackOverflowの以下の質問が参考になると思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985024/uiactivityviewcontroller-share-only-text

iOS8.3を使っていて、Facebookアプリのv29.0以上を使っていると発生するようです。
驚いたことにFacebookアプリを削除すると、正しく動作するようになります。
(FacebookのアカウントはOSの設定で管理されているため、Facebookアプリを削除してもUIActivityViewControllerにFacebookのアイコンが現れ、投稿画面から投稿できます)

5/7にv30.0がリリースされましたが、それでも治っていませんでした。
次のバージョンで修正するとfacebookアプリ開発者から投稿がありました。
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949486035103197/

Comment: やはり、FB側の問題だったのですね。
共有いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: 5/21にリリースされたv31.0でテキストのみ埋め込むケースは修正されたことを確認しました。ただ、テキスト+イメージの両方を埋め込んだ場合、投稿画面にはイメージのみ表示されてテキストが埋め込まれないという方は修正されていませんでした。(Facebookアプリを削除すると、やはり正常にテキストも埋め込まれます)
それと、正常に投稿できているのにあいかわらず「plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated」のログはでています。